# how to pass javascript variables inside another javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, popup

So i need to pass a variable into the window.open() function of js.i know the correct syntax is window.open("http//my.url"); but what if the url i want to enter is a variable..?

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"onClick=window.open("?");>
```

Comment: what kind of variable? where is it located? how can we know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate out your JS from your HTML.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="openwindow" class="btn btn-primary">
```

**JS**

Grab the element by its `id` and declare the `url` variable.

```
var url = 'http://myURL.com';
var node = document.getElementById('openwindow');
```

Attach an `onclick` event to the element and open the URL location based on the `url` variable you specified.

```
node.onclick = function () {
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ke15nsqj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the variable name in the brackets, but with no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a php variable -

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick='window.open("<?php echo $variable; ?>");'>
```